# Extract multiple dataframes from single .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a file that contains several dataframes (each dataframe has its own variables) I want to extract all dataframes from this file and save them in separate files
Is there a way to do this with pandas?

df.txt

```
   col1,  col2,
0,     0,   NaN,
1,     1,   NaN,
2,     2,   2.0,
3,     3,   3.0,
   col3,  col4, col5,
4,     0,   1, 0,
5,     1,   NaN, 1,
   col6,  col7,  
6,     0,   NaN, 
7,     1,   3,
```

Desired result :

df1.csv

```
   col1,  col2,
0,     0,   NaN,
1,     1,   NaN,
2,     2,   2.0,
3,     3,   3.0,
```

df2.csv

```
   col3,  col4, col5,
4,     0,   1, 0,
5,     1,   NaN, 1,
```

df3.csv

```
   col6,  col7,  
6,     0,   NaN, 
7,     1,   3,
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the content of df.csv? That looks like the representation of a Dataframe rather than typical CSV file content

Comment: Actually it's a (.txt) file that contains multiple dataframes, I converted it into (.csv)

Comment: @Husain How did you convert the .txt file to .csv? Just renamed it?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, in order to read it in pandas

Comment: pandas.read_csv accepts any file type as long as the content is in an acceptable format. I.e. you don't have to convert .txt files to .csv

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have an actual CSV file (regardless of its filename extension) rather than what you seem to have?

Comment: you can use [`csplit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) to split the file at each row starting with a blank, no need to write a python script: `csplit -f 'df' -b '%d.csv' -z df.csv '/^ /' '{*}'`

Comment: @Stuart What I wanted to say is that I have a file contains 3 well structured dataframes, that I could read in pandas, I need to divide them into 3 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this in pandas directly but you can easily do this if you know how to recognize the starting line of a new dataframe within the file.
If the file really looks like you posted and a new dataframe starts with some spaces (could be a tab as well) then the following code will create new files for each of the dataframes within the file.

```py
import re


def create_csv(index, lines):
    with open(f"dfs{index}.csv", "w") as new_file:
        new_file.writelines(lines)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("df.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        df_start_indexes = []
        for i, l in enumerate(lines):
            if re.match(r"\s", l):
                df_start_indexes.append(i)

        print(df_start_indexes)
        for df_i, start_line in enumerate(df_start_indexes):
            end_line = df_start_indexes[df_i + 1] if len(df_start_indexes) > df_i + 1 else None
            create_csv(df_i, lines[start_line:end_line])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', header=None)

csv_starts = df.loc[df[0].str.strip().str.startswith('col')].index.to_list()
for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(csv_starts, csv_starts[1:]+[None])):
    df.iloc[a:b].to_csv(f'df{i}.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

1. Read the whole file as `csv`, but there are no commas in there, so it will be a 1-column DataFrame:

   df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', header=None)
2. Get the indices of new-file breaks - the rows with `col`-names in them:

   csv_starts = df.loc[df[0].str.strip().str.startswith('col')].index.to_list()
3. Build index-ranges and save them to file:

   for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(csv_starts, csv_starts[1:]+[None])):
   df.iloc[a:b].to_csv(f'df{i}.csv', index=False, header=False)